# Code Correction with CSV and multiple output

Tags: python, django

I have the following code. It's working perfectly like I want but I have a few problems with it.
1. The CSV file is not getting written 
2. I am getting multiple saves of an object rather than one as I want. (Main problem)
3. How do I send the generated template as an email.

**The Basic idea of the function LCR is that.**

I have some cities or country codes in the database.
I want to compare the codes with values from files uploaded by the users.
after comparing the values I want to see the following result
'1':[("PTCL","0.25"),("TATA","1.25")] . . .
Where '1' is the value fetched from the user file
'PTCL, TATA' are users
'0.25 & 1.25' are the user rates offered for that value.

But I'm getting this

```
    {'25': ['Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888',
    'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888'], 
    '21': ['Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150',
    'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888'], 
    '48': ['Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531',
    'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531'],
     '23': ['Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150',
    'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888'], 
    '33': ['Zong', ' 0.87', 'Zong', ' 0.87', 'Zong', ' 0.87', 'Zong', ' 0.87', 'Zong', ' 0.87', 'Zong', ' 0.87'], 
    '47': ['Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531'], 
    '44': ['Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531'], 
  '42': ['Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531'], 
  '41': ['Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531'], 
 '98': ['Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395'], 
 '451': ['Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531'], 
'91': ['Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395'], 
 '93': ['Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395'], 
'96': ['Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 1.260', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.205', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.030', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'Tata', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.005', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'PTCL', ' 0.305', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', '0.044', 'Zong', ' 5.395', 'Zong', ' 5.395']}
```

I want to see each user once in the result but I am not sure why multiple times they are showing. Maybe it's a loop issue or something.

The second problem is that my CSV file isn't getting written but that's not the main issue. Please check the code and see if there's an error.

```
def LCR(request):
    template = "LCR\LCRGen.html"

    emailadd = Email.objects.all()
    dest = Destination.objects.values_list('dest_num', flat=True)

    ratelist = {}
    csv_file   =  { }
    data_set   =  { }
    io_string  =  { }


    vendor = RateFile.objects.values_list()
    v_count = vendor.count()

    for v_id, v_name, v_file in vendor:
        vendor_name = str(v_name)
#converted into a string so that i may be used to reference for file creation with the vendor name. like this (csv_fileTata)
        vendornames = str(v_name)
#converted into a string to use as an empty dict var name
        vendornames = { }

        for desNum in dest:
            desNum = str(desNum)


            for countvar in range(v_count):

                csv_file[vendor_name] = RateFile.objects.get(id=v_id).ven_file

                data_set[vendor_name] = csv_file[vendor_name].read().decode("UTF-8")

                io_string[vendor_name] = io.StringIO(data_set[vendor_name])
                next(io_string[vendor_name])


                for column in csv.reader(io_string[vendor_name], delimiter=str(u",")):

    #creates a dictionary with the name of the vendor,the number as key and rate as value

                    vendornames[column[0]] = column[1]



                # csvfile.close()


                for venNum, venValue in vendornames.items():



                    venlen = len(venNum)
                    deslen = len(desNum)



                    # csvfile = open('csvfile.csv','w')
                    if venlen >= deslen:


                        if desNum[:-1]==venNum[:-1] and desNum[:-2]==venNum[:-2] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-3]:
                            # print ('====================')
                            # print (venNum)
                            # print (desNum)
                            # print "Works well 1"
                            # print ('====================')

                            # ratelist[desNum] = [vendor_name, venValue]
                            # ratelist[desNum].append(venValue)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(vendor_name))
                            #              for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.items())

                            # thewriter.writerow
                            # ({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })

                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print 'stuff'
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)




                        elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-2] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-3] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-4]:


                                    # print ('====================')
                                    # print (venNum)
                                    # print (desNum)
                                    # print (venValue)
                            # print "Works well 2"
                            # print ('====================')
                            # ratelist[desNum].append(vendor_name)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(venValue)) for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.iteritems())


                            # thewriter.writerow({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue]})




                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print 'stuff'
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)


                        elif desNum[:-1] == desNum[:-3] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-4] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-5]:
                            # ratelist[desNum].append(vendor_name)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(venValue)) for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.iteritems())
                            # thewriter.writerow
                            # ({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print "STUFF"
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)

                                    # print ('====================')
                                    # print (venNum)
                                    # print (desNum)
                                    # print (venValue)
                            # print "Works well3"
                            # print ('====================')

                        elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-4] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-5]:

                            # ratelist[desNum].append(vendor_name)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(venValue)) for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.iteritems())
                            # thewriter.writerow
                            # ({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print "FOUND"
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)



                        elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-5] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-6]:

                            # ratelist[desNum].append(vendor_name)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(venValue))
                            #              for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.iteritems())

                            # print rates
                            # thewriter.writerow
                            # ({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print 'STUFF'
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)




                        else:
                            # thewriter.writerow({'Destinations': [desNum], 'Vendors': [
                            #                    vendor_name], 'Rates': [venValue]})
                            print "HELLO WORLD"

                # thewriter.writerow(
                #     {'Destinations':desNum, 'Vendors':vendor_name, 'Rates':venValue})
                    # csvfile.close()


                    csvfile = open('csvfile.csv','w')
                    headers = ['Destinations', 'Vendors', 'Rates']

                    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
                    thewriter.writeheader()
                    thewriter.writerow({'Destinations':venNum, 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })



    return render (request, template, {"ratelist": ratelist, "emailadd": emailadd } )
```

I want my results to show something like this.

```
{'25':['Tata','0.25','PTCL','1.002','Zong','0.090']
'15':['Tata','1.25','PTCL','0.12','Zong','0.90']}
```