# Django Management Command : 'Command' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django

I have a Management command, that prints out a function output. But after execution it gives an error.

What is the error and how to resolve it?

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from Destinations.models import *
from LCR.views import *

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Generates a LCR when executed '

    def handle(self,*args, **kwargs):
        LCR(self)
```

> (VE) C:\Users\Bitswits 3\Desktop\LCRProject\LeastCostRouting>python
>   manage.py my_dest_commands { '48': ['Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', '
>   0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531', 'Tata', ' 0.531'], '23': ['Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', '
>   4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'Tata', ' 4.150', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888',
>   'PTCL', ' 0.888', 'PTCL', ' 0.888'] }
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 364, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 356, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 283, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 330, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\Bitswits 3\Desktop\LCRProject\LeastCostRouting\Destinations\management\commands\my_dest_commands.py",
>   line 14, in handle
>       print LCR(self)   File "C:\Users\Bitswits 3\Desktop\LCRProject\LeastCostRouting\LCR\views.py", line 269, in LCR
>       return render (request, template, {"ratelist": ratelist, "emailadd": emailadd } )   File
>   "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py",
>   line 30, in render
>       content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)   File
>   "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py",
>   line 68, in render_to_string
>       return template.render(context, request)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py",
>   line 66, in render
>       return self.template.render(context)   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
>   line 205, in render
>       with context.bind_template(self):   File "c:\python27\Lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in **enter**
>       return self.gen.next()   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py",
>   line 263, in bind_template
>       updates.update(processor(self.request))   File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\LCRPRO~1\VE\lib\site-packages\django\template\context_processors.py",
>   line 43, in debug
>       if settings.DEBUG and request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no
>   attribute 'META'

```
def LCR(request):
    template = "LCR\LCRGen.html"

    emailadd = Email.objects.all()
    dest = Destination.objects.values_list('dest_num', flat=True)

    ratelist = {}
    csv_file   =  { }
    data_set   =  { }
    io_string  =  { }


    vendor = RateFile.objects.values_list()
    v_count = vendor.count()

    for v_id, v_name, v_file in vendor:
        vendor_name = str(v_name)
#converted into a string so that i may be used to reference for file creation with the vendor name. like this (csv_fileTata)
        vendornames = str(v_name)
#converted into a string to use as an empty dict var name
        vendornames = { }

        for desNum in dest:
            desNum = str(desNum)


            for countvar in range(v_count):

                csv_file[vendor_name] = RateFile.objects.get(id=v_id).ven_file

                data_set[vendor_name] = csv_file[vendor_name].read().decode("UTF-8")

                io_string[vendor_name] = io.StringIO(data_set[vendor_name])
                next(io_string[vendor_name])


                for column in csv.reader(io_string[vendor_name], delimiter=str(u",")):

    #creates a dictionary with the name of the vendor,the number as key and rate as value

                    vendornames[column[0]] = column[1]



                # csvfile.close()


                for venNum, venValue in vendornames.items():



                    venlen = len(venNum)
                    deslen = len(desNum)



                    # csvfile = open('csvfile.csv','w')
                    if venlen >= deslen:


                        if desNum[:-1]==venNum[:-1] and desNum[:-2]==venNum[:-2] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-3]:
                            # print ('====================')
                            # print (venNum)
                            # print (desNum)
                            # print "Works well 1"
                            # print ('====================')

                            # ratelist[desNum] = [vendor_name, venValue]
                            # ratelist[desNum].append(venValue)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(vendor_name))
                            #              for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.items())

                            # thewriter.writerow
                            # ({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })

                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print 'stuff'
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)







                        elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-2] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-3] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-4]:


                                    # print ('====================')
                                    # print (venNum)
                                    # print (desNum)
                                    # print (venValue)
                            # print "Works well 2"
                            # print ('====================')
                            # ratelist[desNum].append(vendor_name)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(venValue)) for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.iteritems())


                            # thewriter.writerow({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue]})




                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print 'stuff'
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)


                        elif desNum[:-1] == desNum[:-3] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-4] and desNum[:-3] == venNum[:-5]:
                            # ratelist[desNum].append(vendor_name)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(venValue)) for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.iteritems())
                            # thewriter.writerow
                            # ({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print "STUFF"
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)

                                    # print ('====================')
                                    # print (venNum)
                                    # print (desNum)
                                    # print (venValue)
                            # print "Works well3"
                            # print ('====================')

                        elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-4] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-5]:

                            # ratelist[desNum].append(vendor_name)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(venValue)) for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.iteritems())
                            # thewriter.writerow
                            # ({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print "FOUND"
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)



                        elif desNum[:-1] == venNum[:-5] and desNum[:-2] == venNum[:-6]:

                            # ratelist[desNum].append(vendor_name)
                            # rates = dict((desNum, tuple(venValue))
                            #              for desNum, vendor_name in ratelist.iteritems())

                            # print rates
                            # thewriter.writerow
                            # ({'Destinations':[desNum], 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)
                            if vendor_name and venValue in desNum:
                                print 'STUFF'
                            else:
                                ratelist.setdefault(
                                    desNum, []).append(vendor_name)
                            ratelist.setdefault(
                                desNum, []).append(venValue)


                                    # print ('====================')
                            # print (venNum)
                            # print (desNum)
                            # print (venValue)
                            # print "Works well5"
                            # print ('====================')

                        else:
                            # thewriter.writerow({'Destinations': [desNum], 'Vendors': [
                            #                    vendor_name], 'Rates': [venValue]})
                            pass

                # thewriter.writerow(
                #     {'Destinations':desNum, 'Vendors':vendor_name, 'Rates':venValue})
                    # csvfile.close()


                    csvfile = open('csvfile.csv','w')
                    headers = ['Destinations', 'Vendors', 'Rates']

                    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
                    thewriter.writeheader()
                    thewriter.writerow({'Destinations':venNum, 'Vendors':[vendor_name], 'Rates':[venValue] })



    print ( ratelist )

    return render (request, template, {"ratelist": ratelist, "emailadd": emailadd } )
```

Comment: How can we answer this when you haven't even shown the code of the command?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please check now. I forgot to add it

Comment: That doesn't help at all. What is LCR?

Comment: @DanielRoseman LCR is a function that returns that output. I will update the question with the code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman also please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303712/code-correction-with-csv-and-multiple-output) I asked earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Command you pass the command-instance itself to your function.

> ```
> class Command(BaseCommand):
>     help = 'Generates a LCR when executed '
>
>     def handle(self,*args, **kwargs):
>         LCR(self) # <<
> ```

But your LCR() function seems to be a view, sort of, and expect a [request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) instance (HttpRequest) for the render statement at the end. This is, I guess, why you receive this error.

> ```
> def LCR(request):
>     template = "LCR\LCRGen.html"
>     # ....
>     return render (request, template, {"ratelist": ratelist, "emailadd": emailadd } )
> ```

As far as I can see, since you are not using anything by the request instance for your LCR logic, you should encapsulate it from your view function to a separate function so you can call it from both locations.

---

For instance:
Define a new method within your > *LeastCostRouting\LCR\views.py* e.g.

```py
def get_LCR():

    # take everything from the original method starting:
    emailadd = Email.objects.all()

    # ---
    # the other code
    # till:
    print(ratelist)

    return {"ratelist": ratelist, "emailadd": emailadd }
```

And then just call it within your LCR method like:

> ```
> return render (request, template, get_LCR() )
> ```

And in your command method like:

> ```
> def handle(self,*args, **kwargs):
>     get_LCR()
> ```

Comment: encapsulate how ?